# How to mock in Moq Func<object, Class> Property { get; }

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I am stuck with mocking problem using Moq.

How do I mock this property?

```
public interface ICommand {
    Func<object, Document> GetDocument { get; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I mock this property?

By using an actual Function

Given

```
public interface ICommand {
    Func<object, Document> GetDocument { get; }
}
```

Use an actual function in the test and return that from the mocked interface

```
var mock = new Mock<ICommand>();

Func<object, Document> function = (object arg) => {
    //...code to return a document
};

mock.Setup(_ => _.GetDocument).Returns(function);
```

Reference [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) to get a better understanding of how to use the mocking framework.